# Convert PNG to JPG and set transparent background to white with ImageMagick and PHP

Tags: php, image, imagemagick, transparency

How can I use ImageMagick (with the php extension) to set the transparent background to white when converting an image from PNG to JPEG?

Comment: Which php extension, there are three. MagickWand, IMagick or phMagick?

Answer (score 53):

At time of writing, you have not specified which extension you are using, but if you were using the commandline, the command would be:

```
convert image.png -background white -flatten -alpha off image.jpg
```

More information can be found on the [Masking Usage documentation](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/masking/).

Using IMagick for instance, I think you could do this as follows:

*(totally untested, never used IMagick and don't have it installed to test)*

```
$image = new IMagick('image.png');

$flattened = new IMagick();
$flattened->newImage($image->getImageWidth(), $image->getImageHeight(), new ImagickPixel("white"));

$flattened->compositeImage($image, imagick::COMPOSITE_OVER, 0, 0);

$flattened->setImageFormat("jpg");
$flattened->writeImage('image.jpg');

$image->clear();
$image->destroy();
$flattened->clear();
$flattened->destroy();
```

Comment: I believe you should use
`$sizes = $image->getImageGeometry();
$width = $sizes['width'];
$height = $sizes['height'];`

instead of `$image->getWidth(), $image->getHeight()`

Comment: @CappY: That works too, any reason for the function over the other two, except perhaps a few microseconds performance boost?

Comment: @Orbling : `Fatal error: Call to undefined method Imagick::getWidth()`
Dunno if it's works for you.

Comment: @CappY: How bizarre... it's in the doc: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagick-getimagewidth.php

Comment: It's `$image->getImageWidth();` and `$image->getImageHeight();`
I didn't saw these functions. :)

Comment: @Orbling, You use two steps to convert format. First you sets the new format (jpg), then you `writeImage('image.jpg')`. I found that it's not necessary to set the format. It's just enough to write desired image extension when you save image - `writeImage('image.jpg')` or `writeImage('image.gif')`. It converts format automatically. When you check saved images in console using `identify -verbose` they have exactly new formats. But there is no any official docs about this behavior. Should I use `setImageFormat()` first or it is really not necessary?

Comment: @Green: Image Magick itself, or rather the command line version behaves as you say, so I would expect the `writeImage()` command to work the same as you have verified.  As I say above, the code was untested by myself, just written in the browser - as the command to change format existed, I used it just in case.  Dare say it allows the use of non-standard extensions, or output to the browser.  Might be good style to leave it in if it causes no additional time, if it does, I would remove it and allow the automatic conversion.

Comment: Works for GIF too! Thx

Answer (score 5):

If you are using the Imagick extension:

```
<?php
// load the source transparent png
$i = new IMagick('image.png');

// set the background to white
// you can also use 'rgb(255,255,255)' in place of 'white'
$i->setImageBackgroundColor(new ImagickPixel('white'));

// flattens multiple layers
$i = $i->flattenImages();

// the output format
$i->setImageFormat('jpg');

// save to disk
$i->writeImage('image.jpg');

// and/or output directly
// header('Content-Type: '.$i->getFormat());
// echo $i->getImageBlob();

// cleanup
$i->clear();
$i->destroy();
```

Comment: Old answer but __flattenImages__ is now deprecated and the recommended way is  

`mergeImageLayers(Imagick::LAYERMETHOD_FLATTEN)`  

http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.mergeimagelayers.php